# Что дописать в htaccess для переадресации с www?

Tags: .htaccess

Вот так выглядит htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://мойдомен.ру [R=301,L]
```

То есть я сделал переадресации с хттп на хттпс и что то с индексом.пхп
Но никак не соображу что дописать, чтобы заходя сюда: [https://www.мойдомен.ру](https://www.%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D1%80%D1%83) -заходил туда [https://мойдомен.ру](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D1%80%D1%83)
p.s. прошу повторно обратить внимание, что включен хттпс.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обычно у хостингов такое есть в админки, может там по тыкать стоит и все. Если нужно быстро и легко решить.

Comment: хостинг ру-центр, не вижу там такого в настройках..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Делал так у себя. Попробуйте, должно сработать.

Comment: это вместо чего или просто дописать ниже?

Comment: Помогло, при таком заходе на сайт: https://www.мойдомен.ру - заходит, только скрипт перестает работать, но это видимо его надо править..